# Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[contains(text(),'New patient')]"}

Tags: jmeter, webdriver

My application having a pop-up which may come in any tab out of ten at any time.
I have written a webdriver script as below.
But on which tab the pop-up is not coming I am getting exception

Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[contains(text(),'New patient')]"}

The else condation is never called.

```
var new_patient ="//button[contains(text(),'New patient')]";
if(new_patient !=0){
var NewPatient = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'New patient')]"));
NewPatient.click();
WDS.log.info("New patient clicked");
}
else 
{
WDS.log.info( "it is not Clicked")  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Try Catch Mechanism instead of if else ..

something like

```
Try 
{
WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'New patient')]")).click();
}
Catch(Exception e)
{
WDS.log.info( "it is not Clicked") 
}
```

for more info on selenium tests please read [this article](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2017/02/using-selenium-webdriver-run-scalable-load-tests/)